# Are smarties halal?

Tags: halal-haram, food

Are smarties haram if so why aren’t they? And if they are haram which colours are haram are all off them? I heard some people say it’s about the dyes they use. Please explain.

Comment: "Smarties" can refer to very different candies depending on what country you're in. And even if they're referring to the same candy, the actual ingredients can still vary by region, and rulings on whether those individual ingredients are halal or not may even vary by Islamic school. This is really unanswerable without some sort of scope.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not a scholar so take this with a grain of salt, but I don't think they are haram to eat. I think they are perfectly fine to eat; whoever told you they are must have their facts mixed up. The dyes they use is artificial, meaning it was made in a factory instead of naturally, so do not worry, you will not be judged.

Answer (score 1):

I googled it just now and they say it’s suitable for a vegetarian diet but not halal certified. I think you may have M&Ms mixed up with smarties as M&Ms are something we cannot eat.